# Are there any other tools like whois which can be used to obtain domain certificates using command line?

Tags: domain, domain-registration, whois, certificate

I needed to collect certain information from domain certificate, i was looking into "whois" but it gives a "TLD has no whois server" in certain cases.

Also does the information provided in the certificate differ for different domains?

And is there a limit in using whois from a ip? If yes what is it in term of concurrency and the number of times it can be queried ?

Answer (score 0):

A few questions.

- What "certain information" are you trying to retrieve?
- By "certificate" do you mean an SSL certificate? Or do you just want the domain registration information? This isn't clear in your question.
- Do you have examples of the domains/TLDs that aren't working?

Yes, some domain registrars limit the total number of WHOIS looksup per-IP. The limit is down to them. You'd need to give examples to find out more.

Just a stab in the dark here - *you're not trying to domain-snipe are you?*

Comment: The certain details would include the registraion date, its expiry, the domain registrar name, the status of the website etc.               I just want the domain registration details and not the ssl certificate.                                                          Try whois for any .bt domain to get the "TLD has no whois server" error.                                                              I am not trying to do a domain snipe.

Comment: The full error I get is "This TLD has no whois server, but you can access the whois database at http://www.nic.bt/". In this case they've provided their own interface to the whois database (probably so they can control the information more). One solution would be to script something which POSTs a query to their website and parses the result. But in short, unless they provided a public WHOIS server, the standard WHOIS tool won't work.